# How did Xindi contact trans-dimensional beings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

After Archer got captured and he told some dirty secrets to Degra and good council members, it was shown that they called on a meeting with trans-dimensional being for doubt-clearance. How did they really contact her?

Comment: @DVK Reasons to remove star-trek and tv tag?

Comment: Because the question is specific to Enterprise (and not the rest of the franchise) and NOT (as asked) restricted to the TV show (if there were book spinoffs, they may contain the answer).

Answer (score 4):

Once again, I believe we're stuck with a case of an unexplained mystery. Presumably, the Sphere Builders left some sort of signaling device for just such occasions. What that device was and how it works were never explained.